# Exception handling in the JAXRS client

Tags: java, jax-rs, httpclient

I am using JAXRS client to connect to my server. On the happy path, this works fine, but when my server throws an exception, the client receives `Caused by: javax.ws.rs.NotAcceptableException: HTTP 406 Not Acceptable`

`My Client Code is:`

```
public interface ConfigClient {

    @PUT
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/testMe")
    Map<String, Object> saveAttributeStore(MyInput myInput);

}

public ConfigClient create(String url) {

final ResponseExceptionMapper exceptionMapper = response -> new RuntimeException();
    final List<Object> providers = List.of(new JacksonJsonProvider(), exceptionMapper);

    ConfigClient configClient = JAXRSClientFactory.create(url, ConfigClient.class, providers);

    HTTPClientPolicy clientPolicy = WebClient.getConfig(configClient).getHttpConduit().getClient();
    clientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(1000);
    clientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(3000);

    return configClient;
}
```

`And Server Endpoint is:`

```
@PutMapping(path = "testMe",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Map<String, Object> createAttributeStore(MyInput input) {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: question is that I am getting client-side error 406, where I was expecting some 5XX error. Or not at-least 406.